# How to pass different payload for multiple REST post request using grequest in Python

Tags: python, api, rest

I have created a list of payload/param/data which need to pass as a param for every post request. I am using grequest to send the request parallelly. So the idea is for each parallel post request the param should be from the list. But what I am observing with my code is, the request is happening with the same payload from the list for every request, it is not accessing all the payload from the list.

I have tried two different ways, please help what is wrong with it, I am kind of lost because I have tested the same thing with different URLs and headers it works why is not working for param/data/payload for post request.

Below is my code:

```
for i in range(0, count):
 list_payload_user.append(fp1())
    
url2 = "https:xxxxxyzzz/rest/v3/edit-user-requests/" + devid
```

headers = {'Authorization': token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

#this 1 way I have tried:-

```
rs = [grequests.post(url2, headers=headers, data=final_pl1(), hooks={'response': res}) for i in range(0, len(list_payload))]
```

#here I have used a function - final_pl1(), which should get called every time, I have seen it is sending a different payload, but when grequest sending the request it is sending with 1st payload only.

#another way:-

```
rs = [grequests.post(url2, headers=headers, data=pl, hooks={'response': res}) for pl in list_payload_user]
```

#here I have used the list, grequest is sending with 1st payload from the list for every post request.

```
resp = grequests.map(rs, exception_handler=err_handler)
print('Maped response status code ==> ', resp)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please show your definition of `fp1()` method and also check if `list_payload_user` indeed have different elements.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia thank you for your response.
fp1() - is generating payload for mentioned list - list_payload_user, and i am sure that the list elements are different. There is no problem with that, the problem is while fetching the list element for concurrent Post request from that same list.